# How to level up in xenoblade with 78 chars?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

I have a group with 78 levels, just before battle with AIHTIROL, but I'm stuck.

How can I level up 5~7 levels before this boss? Where can I level up fast enough?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most convenient enemies are on the [Bionis' leg](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Bionis%27_Leg) and then at the [Satorl Marsh](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Satorl_Marsh).

- Start your level up at the [Bionis' leg](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Bionis%27_Leg), with their powerful enemies whose level is usually between 74 and 80. There are powerful [Gogols](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Gogol) around the [Raguel Lake](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Raguel_Lake) (level 78-80). Otherwise there are other powerful enemies at the [Windy Cave](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Windy_Cave), [Magnis Arduns](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Magnis_Ardun) at [Gaur Plain](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Gaur_Plain) too (with the unique [Territorial Rotbart](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Territorial_Rotbart)).
- Once you will level up 1-2 levels, go to the [Satorl Marsh](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Satorl_Marsh), with their powerful enemies whose level is usually between 81 and 85. Lots of them can be found almost everywhere during the night. There are also some powerful [Gogols](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Gogol) everytime at the [Soter Ruins](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Soter_Ruins) (lead by level 85 [Indomitable Daulton](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Indomitable_Daulton)) and [Frost Nebulas](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Frost_Nebula) (level 80) near the [Sororal Statues](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Sororal_Statues) when the weather is foggy too. Please do not go visiting the Bunnies near the [Glowing Obelisk](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Glowing_Obelisk). You might encounter level 108 [Despotic Arsene](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Despotic_Arsene) which is [the 3rd most powerful enemy of the entire game](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Superboss) (the most powerful one outside the Valak Mountain).

The best way to defeat AIHTIROL is praying and expecting a miracle. :-P It is likely the most difficult boss of the game. However level 78 should be OK for defeating her. I have already defeated her with a group at level 73-74. Choose the best group possible. You need enemies whith strong ether skills. Avoid Reyn which is weak against ether enemies like telethias. The best group possible contains Sharla, Shulk and Melia (or Fiora) IMHO.